# Redirect to Dashboard by embedding Dashboard URL inside LWC

Tags: salesforce, dashboard, lwc

I have a custom Dashboard and a custom LWC and an Account record Page as shown below.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/8JFeR.png

On Dashboard tab, I have embedded the custom LWC and inside which I have added Dashboard URL as an Iframe but it's not redirecting correctly to the dashboard when clicked on Dashboard tab.

Below is my LWC code

```js
export default class DynamicDashboard extends NavigationMixin(LightningElement) {

  @track iframeURL;
  @track a_Record_URL;
        
  connectedCallback(){
    this.a_Record_URL = window.location.origin;
  }

  @wire(getRecord, {
    recordId: "$recordId",
    fields
  })
  loadFields({error, data}){
    if(data){                                
      this.iframeURL = 'this.a_Record_URL/desktopDashboards/dashboardApp.app?dashboardId=01Z4y000001O93MEAS&displayMode=view&networkId=000000000000000';
    }
  }
}
```

`this.iframeURL` is not populating correctly I believe due to which When I click on Dashboard tab on Account record page it says 'URL is invalid. Please try with correct URL'.

Please help me out on this.
I have tried most of the possible alternatives but it's not working.

Please help me out team.

Thanking you in anticipation.

Answer (score 0):

Don't include the base domain if you want to show only dashboard in a custom component. check out this one.

HTML

```
<iframe
src={iframeURL}
height={height}
width={width}
id="ifram-1"
frameborder="0"
></iframe>
```

JS

```
@track height = '870px';
@track iframeURL= '';
@track width = '100%';

 @wire(getRecord, {
    recordId: "$recordId",
    fields
})
loadFields({error, data}){
  if(data){                                
this.iframeURL = '/desktopDashboards/dashboardApp.app? 
dashboardId=01Z4y000001O93MEAS&displayMode=view&networkId=000000000000000';    
}
```

Comment: You're missing the point. Concatenation is wrongly done "this.iframeURL = this.a_Record_URL + '/......"

Comment: You're right, that might be the issue.

Answer (score 0):

After formatting the code, it appears pretty obvious there is an issue with concatenation. Please try to always format correctly your code, this help avoid a lot of errors.

Concatenation between variable and static string can be achieve in several ways:

```js
// Basic using + operator
this.iframeURL = this.a_Record_URL + '/desktopDashboards/dashboardApp.app?dashboardId=01Z4y000001O93MEAS&displayMode=view&networkId=000000000000000';

// Using backtick
this.iframeURL = `${this.a_Record_URL}/desktopDashboards/dashboardApp.app?dashboardId=01Z4y000001O93MEAS&displayMode=view&networkId=000000000000000`;

// Using array
this.iframeURL = [
  this.a_Record_URL,
  '/desktopDashboards/dashboardApp.app?dashboardId=01Z4y000001O93MEAS&displayMode=view&networkId=000000000000000'
].join('')
```